# Unicode character (urdu) from Oracle to Unix

Tags: database, oracle, redhat, rhel

I'm trying to select some urdu characters from Oracle database table on linux shell on red hat server but it is displaying as "??????". Below is the output on shell

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select * from urdu_test;

### MSISDN

### CUSTOMER_NAME

923165106151
???? ???? ??? ???? ?? ?? ??? ?? ???? ???

on DB side below are the characterset parameters.
[image: db characterset]

on red hat server i export the NLS_LANG variable as below
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF
[image: NLS_LANG on server]

But i'm still unable to select the urdu characters from db. On DB side i can insert and select the characters manually.
Any support will be appreciated, what variables need to be check on linux side?

Comment: What is $ABC at the end of your question? What terminal emulator are you using to run SQL\*Plus, and what are the language/character encoding for that emulator and the OS?

Comment: $ABC is a variable in which NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UT8 . I'm using xshell terminal to run sqlplus. Please find below the locale out                           [root@unica-app-server ~]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: by doing locale -a, i can find my supported language:ur_PK
ur_PK.utf8. urdu urdu fonts are already install on the server

Comment: What is the character set of your Linux terminal? Try `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`

Comment: What is your `NLS_LANG` value? `UTF` or `UT8` or `UTF8`? You have written all of them.

Comment: Locale charmap =UTF-8, echo $LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: one more update now i set NLS_LANG as below su - oracle then export variable as export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 then is open sqlplus as sqlplus / as sysdba then i query the same table and i'm able to select the characters successfully as                                                            SQL> SELECT * FROM URDU_TEST;

MSISDN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTOMER_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
92334354354
نہیں ھوتا کسی طبیب سے اس مرض کا علاج وصی

Comment: but when i close the terminal and close the session and open it again the query the same table same way, it is appearing as ??????. I think the problem is somewhere in export NLS_LANG through su - oracle. Can you please guide about this

Comment: Add `export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` to your personal `.bashrc` file.